# How to introduce NA's for missing elements from converting a json object to a data frame

Tags: json, r, dataframe

How do I introduce NA's into a data frame for the elements that don't exist for my json array?

```
library(jsonlite)
json <- "[\n {\n \"input\": \"211\",\n\"date\": \"2015-03-27T07:36:37.581Z\" \n},\n{\n \"input\": \"215\",\n\"stop\": \"JEWEL LAKE and STRAWBERRY NNE: 0215\",\n\"date\": \"2015-03-27T07:36:44.224Z\" \n} \n]"
json_list <- fromJSON(json)
```

I am expecting to get a data frame back with two rows, with columns for the listed index, and the elements from the json array if they exist or not in this example they are input, stop, and date.

Comment: can you also give the output you get , because if I run this, it gives a dataframe with 2 rows and 3 columns (input,date,stop) with a NA in json_list[1,"stop"]

Comment: I was using rjson which was making it a nested list. Thanks.  Your update worked.